# Ext.Net - Line Charts - Basic Line with colored area

Tags: charts, background-color, ext.net

I need to customize a 'Line Chart - Basic line' inserting colored areas in the background as in the attached image:

[image]

Is there a simple solution for this?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is web forms or mvc?

Comment: Web forms, thank you